# Python: Loop over NDB entity model

Tags: python, class, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a class/NDB Entity Model defined as follows:

```
class CashModel(ndb.Model):
    "Models a Cash record"
    # Name, Balance, Interest Rate
    accountName = ndb.StringProperty()
    interestRate = ndb.FloatProperty()
    balance = ndb.FloatProperty()
    accountType = ndb.StringProperty()
    futureView = ndb.JsonProperty()
    time_stored = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Once values are added to the `class`, a print out of it looks like this:

```
CashModel(accountName=u'Bank', accountType=u'cash', balance=1000.0, futureView=None, interestRate=5.0, time_stored=datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 7, 18, 33, 3, 925601))
```

How do I loop over the key/value pairs of this class, so the output would be something like:

```
accountName, Bank
accountType, cash
balance, 1000.0
futureView, None
interestRate, 5.0
time_stored, datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 7, 18, 33, 3, 925601)
```

Looked through other answer on S.O., but none seemed a good fit. Simple solution using a built-in method would be best. TIA

Comment: What do you want is a "pretty" output for this class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `to_dict(include=None, exclude=None)` instance method to convert your model object to dictionary and then use `iteritems()` to iterate over key/value pairs

```
to_dict(include=None, exclude=None)
```

Returns a dict containing the model's property values.

[Check this link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_to_dict)

Answer (score 2):

Add an `__iter__()` method to your class which yields from `self.__dict__.items()`.

```
>>> class Test:
        def __init__(self):
            self.a = 1
            self.b = 2
        def __iter__(self): yield from self.__dict__.items()

>>>[t for t in Test()]
[('b', 2), ('a', 1)]
```

Comment: Actually, I do not know how NDB works. This works for ordinary Python but as for NDB I cannot say. Stand by while I find out.

Comment: I can't find out. Let me know if it helps. If not, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can also over the `__repr__` and `__str__` methods of the class:

```
In [7]: class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = "A"
        self.baz = "B"
        self.bug = "C"
    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join(['{}={}'.format(k,v) for (k, v) in self.__dict__.items()])
    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(['{}={}'.format(k,v) for (k, v) in self.__dict__.items()])
   ...:     

In [8]: print Foo()
baz=B
bar=A
bug=C

In [9]: Foo()
Out[9]: 
baz=B
bar=A
bug=C
```

Here is a `__str__` method that does what you want:

```
In [39]: class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = "A"
        self.baz = "B"
        self.bug = "C"
    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join(['{}={}'.format(k,v) for (k, v) in self.__dict__.items()])
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__+'('+';'.join(['{}={}'.format(k,v) for (k, v) in self.__dict__.items()])+')'
   ....:     

In [40]: print Foo()
Foo(baz=B;bar=A;bug=C)
```

Comment: The only change I would apply here is adding the class name at the beginning and maybe indentation to the key/value. But, sure, that depends  the case.